# Mocking a new object inside another method testing

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have a class which contains method like

```java
private MqttWrapper createNewMqttWrapperInstance(EdamsCell deviceCell) {
    MqttWrapper mqttWrapper = new MqttWrapper();
    MqttClientConnectionManager mqttClientConnectionManager = context.getMqttClientConnectionManager();
    MqttClientConnection mqttClientConnection = mqttClientConnectionManager.getMqttClientConnection(mqttWrapper);

    setMqttWrapperProperties(mqttWrapper, AWSIotConnectionStatus.CONNECTED);
    log.info("New instance of MqttWrapper created for device cell {}", deviceCell);

    return mqttWrapper;
}
```

My test method is

```java
try(MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(MqttWrapper.class, (mock, context) -> {})){
    mockMethodCalls();
    doReturn(mqttClientConnection).when(mqttClientConnectionManager).getMqttClientConnection(); ->I am not able to control this as there in code a new object is passed. 
    mqttWrapperFactoryImpl = spy(new MqttWrapperFactoryImpl(context));
    outputMqttWrapper = mqttWrapperFactoryImpl.getMqttWrapperForSiteId(SITE_ID);

    assertEquals(expectedMqttWrapper, outputMqttWrapper);
    
    // verify(mqttClientConnectionManager, times(1)).getMqttClientConnection(IOT_ENDPOINT, deviceResponseListener,
    //         CELL, new MqttWrapper());
    verify(mqttClientConnectionManager, times(1)).getMqttClientConnection( sample);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mqttClientConnectionManager);
}
```

I want to mock this b object creation so that I can control the methodC and verify the same after assertion. I dont want to use PowerMockito.

I can't control the invocation method also, neither I am able to verify the test calling.
I tried MockitoConstruction but was unable to do so.

Comment: It can not be done by mockito. You have to refactor your code or change to powermockito

Comment: Please improve your question by showing us your attempt and what failed.

Comment: Updated code. I am unable to verify the commented line of test case

Answer (score 0):

Mockito framework can be used to mock the creation of the B object by mocking the behavior of the constructor;

```
B mockB = Mockito.mock(B.class);

Mockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockB);

yourObject.methodA();

Mockito.verify(yourObject).methodC(mockB);
```

Comment: I dont want to use powerMocktio.whenNew method.

Comment: Then, if your code look like this;
    public class A {
        private final B b;

        public A(B b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void methodA() {
            // --- some code ---
            methodC(b);
        }
    }

you can create a mock instance of B and pass it to your A instance

    B mockB = mock(B.class);
    A a = new A(mockB);
    a.methodA();

Comment: I tried using MockedConstruction on B class. I can mock the method but when I am verifying the call after assertion it's getting failed. 
I did something like this.
```
try(MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(B.class){

--- assertEquals( )--- done
verify(yourClassObject, times(1)).methodC() ? here I am not getting how can I verify methodC onvocation as i dont have the mock object returned from that class. 
}
```

Comment: ArgumentCaptor can be used with Mockito's verify() method;

import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.MockedConstruction;

try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(B.class)) {

    yourClassObject.methodA();

    ArgumentCaptor<B> bCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(B.class);
    verify(yourClassObject, times(1)).methodC(bCaptor.capture());

    B mockedB = bCaptor.getValue();
    assertNotNull(mockedB);
}